# Static library with third party libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I'm looking for the answer to following question:

Is there any possibility to create a static library which uses other static third party libraries so the main application will need just to link my custom static library and all other functions will be included into that library? I'd like to achieve that in Visual Studio just by proper configuration of solution/project.

Currently when I'll use my library in test application I'm getting a lot of `unresolved external symbol` errors.

Comment: You have to link all the 3rd party libraries or merge. A static library will not merge on its own. You need to manually do that.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there is a way to make it more automated. I saw a project which somehow does that and did not found any references to lib.exe.